# iOS: How to redirect a UIWebView while updating the back history?

Tags: javascript, ios, redirect, uiwebview

I have coded a simple browser to which I set the start page to www.google.com (using the `loadRequest` method of WebView).

Now the thing is that I have added a button to the app which takes the user to another webpage, lets say www.yahoo.com (also using the `loadRequest` method).

Everything works perfectly, except when I am trying to go back to the previous page in my browsing history (in this case going from www.google.com to www.yahoo.com). It seems like the "redirect" is not registered in the browser history.

I have also tried redirecting the user through JavaScript directly by changing the `window.location.href` but this does not seem to work either.

How could I enable the user to go back to my start page by pressing the back button, having first been redirected.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking exactly at....

if you simply wants to go back or forward as same as browser. then it is easy get it :

Just add two `UIButton's` and the `UIwebViewDelegate` ,then this action will do the needful

```
- (IBAction)goback:(id)sender {
    if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
        [_webView goBack];
    }
}

- (IBAction)goFwd:(id)sender {
    if ([_webView canGoForward]) {
        [_webView goForward];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am already using this. The problem is rather that when I redirect a user to a certain page from my start page with the push of a UIButton it does not get registered in the history, so I cannot go back, when I should be able to.

Comment: **my start page** , What type of page and what you are expecting after push ..?